# Form is not checking that field is empty or if the requirements are met

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I wrote out a Form entry but when debugging the form was not reading whether the field was empty and still submitting regardless if the entry (mailto is a test example, planning to switch it when done). It also is not checking the specific entries like if the password is under the limit or if the password matches the confirm password field.

```js
function FirstName()
{
    var fname = document.forms["form"]["txtFirst"].value;

    if(fname = "")
    {
       alert("First Name is required");  
       return false;  
    }

}

function LastName()
{
    var lname = document.forms["form"]["txtLast"].value;

    if(lname = "")
    {
       alert("Last Name is required");  
       return false;  
    }

}

function Address()
{
    var address = document.forms["form"]["txtAdd"].value;

    if(address = "")
    {
       alert("Address is required");  
       return false;  
    }
}

function City()
{
    var city = document.forms["form"]["txtCity"].value;

    if(city = "")
    {
       alert("City is required");  
       return false;  
    }
}

function PostalCode()
{
    var city = document.forms["form"]["txtPC"].value;

    if(city = "")
    {
       alert("Postal Code is required");  
       return false;  
    }
}

function ProvinceValues()
{
    var province = document.forms["form"]["txtPro"].value;

    if(province = "")
    {
        alert("Province field is required");
        return false;
    }
    
    if(province != "ON" || "QC" || "ON" || "MN" || "SK" || "AB" || "BC")
    {
        alert("Invalid initials for Province");  
        return false;
    }
}

function Age()
{
    var age = document.forms["form"]["numAge"].value;

    if(age = "")
    {
       alert("Age is required");  
       return false;  
    }

    if(age < 13)
    {
        alert("Age is lower than the requirement (Must be 13 or older to register");
        return false;
    }
}

function VerifyPassword() 
{  
    var pw = document.forms["form"]["passPass"].value;
    var pwC = document.forms["form"]["passCPass"].value;    


    //check empty password field  
    if(pw == "") 
    {  
       alert("Password field is required");  
       return false;  
    }
   
    if(pw.length < 6) 
    {  
       alert("Password length must be atleast 6 characters");  
       return false;  
    }
} 

function ConfirmPassword()
{
    var pw = document.forms["form"]["passPass"].value;
    var pwC = document.forms["form"]["passCPass"].value;    
    
    if(pwC == "") 
    {  
        alert("Confirm Password field is required");  
        return false;  
    }

    if(pw != pwC)
    {
      alert("Passwords do not match");
      return false;
    }

}

function Email()
{
    var email = document.forms["form"]["txtEmail"].value;

    if(email = "")
    {
       alert("Email is required");  
       return false;  
    }
}
```

```html
    <form name="form" onsubmit="FirstName() && LastName() && Address() && City() && PostalCode() && ProvinceValues() && Age() && VerifyPassword()  && ConfirmPassword()" method="post" action="mailto:jjohn@JJohnsonRE.ca">

    <label for="fname">First Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="txtFirst" maxlength="100" placeholder="Your First Name"><br><br>

    <label for="lname">Last Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="txtLast" name="txtLast"maxlength="100" placeholder="Your Last Name"><br><br>

    <label for="address">Address:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="txtAdd" maxlength="100" placeholder="Address"><br><br>

    <label for="city">City:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="txtCity" maxlength="100" placeholder="City"><br><br>
    
    <label for="postalCode">Postal Code:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="txtPC" maxlength="100" placeholder="Postal Code"><br><br>
    
    <label for="province">Province: (Must use initials)</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="txtPro" maxlength="100" placeholder="Province"><br><br>

    <label for="age">Age:</label><br>
    <input type="number" name="numAge" maxlength="100" placeholder="Age"><br><br>

    <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" name="passPass" id="passPass" maxlength="100" placeholder="Password"><br><br>

    <span id="message"></span>


    <label for="Cpassword">Confirm Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" id="passCPass" name="passCPass" maxlength="100" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
    
    <span id="messageC"></span>
    <span id="confirm"></span>


    <label>Your Email:</label><br>
    <input name="txtEmail" type="email" maxlength="100" placeholder="Email"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Register Now">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear Form">

        </form>

    <script src="Assignment4.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your `||` statements in provinces is completely invalid syntax. Use something like: `if(!["ON","QC","ON","MN","SK","AB","BC"].includes(province))`. Otherwise using `||` you need `if(province != 'ON' || province != 'QC' || ....`

Answer (score -1):

Two issues:

1. you need return true/false within `onsubmit`, in your code you only execute all the functions but don't return anything
2. most of your functions have single `=` in the `if`, which means you are assigning value to the variable, not comparing it.

```js
function FirstName()
{
    var fname = document.forms["form"]["txtFirst"].value;

    if(fname == "")
    {
       alert("First Name is required");  
       return false;  
    }
    return true;
}

function LastName()
{
    var lname = document.forms["form"]["txtLast"].value;

    if(lname == "")
    {
       alert("Last Name is required");  
       return false;  
    }
    return true;
}

function Address()
{
    var address = document.forms["form"]["txtAdd"].value;

    if(address == "")
    {
       alert("Address is required");  
       return false;  
    }
    return true;
}

function City()
{
    var city = document.forms["form"]["txtCity"].value;

    if(city == "")
    {
       alert("City is required");  
       return false;  
    }
    return true;
}

function PostalCode()
{
    var city = document.forms["form"]["txtPC"].value;

    if(city == "")
    {
       alert("Postal Code is required");  
       return false;  
    }
    return true;
}

function ProvinceValues()
{
    var province = document.forms["form"]["txtPro"].value;

    if(province == "")
    {
        alert("Province field is required");
        return false;
    }
    
    if(!["ON" , "QC" , "ON" , "MN" , "SK" , "AB" , "BC"].includes(province.toUpperCase()))
    {
        alert("Invalid initials for Province");  
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function Age()
{
    var age = document.forms["form"]["numAge"].value;

    if(age == "")
    {
       alert("Age is required");  
       return false;  
    }

    if(age < 13)
    {
        alert("Age is lower than the requirement (Must be 13 or older to register");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function VerifyPassword() 
{  
    var pw = document.forms["form"]["passPass"].value;
    var pwC = document.forms["form"]["passCPass"].value;    


    //check empty password field  
    if(pw == "") 
    {  
       alert("Password field is required");  
       return false;  
    }
   
    if(pw.length < 6) 
    {  
       alert("Password length must be atleast 6 characters");  
       return false;  
    }
    return true;
} 

function ConfirmPassword()
{
    var pw = document.forms["form"]["passPass"].value;
    var pwC = document.forms["form"]["passCPass"].value;    
    
    if(pwC == "") 
    {  
        alert("Confirm Password field is required");  
        return false;  
    }

    if(pw != pwC)
    {
      alert("Passwords do not match");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function Email()
{
    var email = document.forms["form"]["txtEmail"].value;
    if(email == "")
    {
       alert("Email is required");  
       return false;  
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<form name="form" onsubmit="return FirstName() && LastName() && Address() && City() && PostalCode() && ProvinceValues() && Age() && VerifyPassword()  && ConfirmPassword()" method="post" action="mailto:jjohn@JJohnsonRE.ca">

    <label for="fname">First Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="txtFirst" maxlength="100" placeholder="Your First Name"><br><br>

    <label for="lname">Last Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="txtLast" name="txtLast"maxlength="100" placeholder="Your Last Name"><br><br>

    <label for="address">Address:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="txtAdd" maxlength="100" placeholder="Address"><br><br>

    <label for="city">City:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="txtCity" maxlength="100" placeholder="City"><br><br>
    
    <label for="postalCode">Postal Code:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="txtPC" maxlength="100" placeholder="Postal Code"><br><br>
    
    <label for="province">Province: (Must use initials)</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="txtPro" maxlength="100" placeholder="Province"><br><br>

    <label for="age">Age:</label><br>
    <input type="number" name="numAge" maxlength="100" placeholder="Age"><br><br>

    <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" name="passPass" id="passPass" maxlength="100" placeholder="Password"><br><br>

    <span id="message"></span>


    <label for="Cpassword">Confirm Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" id="passCPass" name="passCPass" maxlength="100" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
    
    <span id="messageC"></span>
    <span id="confirm"></span>


    <label>Your Email:</label><br>
    <input name="txtEmail" type="email" maxlength="100" placeholder="Email"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Register Now">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear Form">

        </form>

    <script src="Assignment4.js"></script>
```

Suggestion, instead of using `alert` (which is annoying, especially that it only tells user about a single field), highlight all the problematic fields instead.

```js
const form = document.forms["form"];
function isFilled()
{
  let ret = true; //return value;
  // check every fields in the form
  for(let i = 0; i < form.length; i++)
  {
    const id = form[i].name || form[i].id;
    if (!id || id == "passCPass")
      continue;

    const field = form[id],
          value = field.value;

    let r = true,
        msg = "";

    switch(id)
    {
      case "txtPro":
        r = ["ON" , "QC" , "ON" , "MN" , "SK" , "AB" , "BC"].includes(value.toUpperCase());
        if (!r)
          msg = "Invalid initials for Province";

        break;

      case "numAge":
        r = value > 12;
        if (!r)
          msg = "Age is lower than the requirement (Must be 13 or older to register";

        break;

      case "passPass":
        r = value.length > 5;
        if (!r)
          msg = "Password length must be atleast 6 characters";

        const escape = /[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g,
              specialCharsAllow = "~`!@#$%^&*()-_+=", //list of required characters
              specialCharsDisallow = "[]\{}|;':\",./<>?", //list of not allowed characters
              specialCharsGood = value.match(new RegExp("[" + specialCharsAllow.replace(escape, '\\$&') + "]"));

        if (!specialCharsGood)
          msg += (msg ? "\n" : "") + `Required special characters ${specialCharsAllow}`;

        const specialCharsBad = value.match(new RegExp("[" + specialCharsDisallow.replace(escape, '\\$&') + "]"));
        if (specialCharsBad)
          msg += (msg ? "\n" : "") + `Not allowed ${specialCharsDisallow}`;

        r &= specialCharsGood ? true : false;
        r &= specialCharsBad ? false : true;

        const cr = value == form.passCPass.value;
        r &= cr;
        form.passCPass.classList.toggle("error", !cr); //set/reset error class on passCPass
        if (cr)
          form.passCPass.removeAttribute("title");
        else
        {
          msg += (msg ? "\n" : "") +"Passwords do not match"
          form.passCPass.setAttribute("title", msg);
        }
        break;
    }
    field.classList.toggle("error", !r); //set/reset error class on current field

    if (msg)
      field.setAttribute("title", msg); //add tooltip
    else
      field.removeAttribute("title");

    ret &= r; //combine total return value with current using bitwise AND
  }
  return ret ? true : false;
}
```

```css
.error
{
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<form name="form" onsubmit="return isFilled()" method="post" action="mailto:jjohn@JJohnsonRE.ca">

    <label for="fname">First Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="txtFirst" maxlength="100" placeholder="Your First Name" required><br><br>

    <label for="lname">Last Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="txtLast" name="txtLast"maxlength="100" placeholder="Your Last Name" required><br><br>

    <label for="address">Address:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="txtAdd" maxlength="100" placeholder="Address" required><br><br>

    <label for="city">City:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="txtCity" maxlength="100" placeholder="City" required><br><br>
    
    <label for="postalCode">Postal Code:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="txtPC" maxlength="100" placeholder="Postal Code" required><br><br>
    
    <label for="province">Province: (Must use initials)</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="txtPro" maxlength="100" placeholder="Province" required><br><br>

    <label for="age">Age:</label><br>
    <input type="number" name="numAge" maxlength="100" placeholder="Age" required><br><br>

    <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" name="passPass" id="passPass" maxlength="100" placeholder="Password" required><br><br>

    <span id="message"></span>


    <label for="Cpassword">Confirm Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" id="passCPass" name="passCPass" maxlength="100" placeholder="Password" required><br><br>
    
    <span id="messageC"></span>
    <span id="confirm"></span>


    <label>Your Email:</label><br>
    <input name="txtEmail" type="email" maxlength="100" placeholder="Email" required><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Register Now">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear Form">

        </form>

    <script src="Assignment4.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did that but now it only works for the first name, not the last name

Comment: how would I highlight the problem fields?

Comment: your functions don't return true if field is valid.

Comment: thank you. If I can ask you one more thing while this question is still open, how do I require special characters for things like password (must require one special character and numbers)

Comment: I was reluctant even respond after your down vote, but I'll give you a break this one time since you are new here ;) Check out second snippet